# how two successive signal assignment (one with delay) work in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have a piece of code like this in a process:

```
A <= '1';
A <= '0' after 5 sec;
```

Does it set A to 1 at first and then set A to 0 after 5 seconds? If not, what should I tweak?

Comment: You could schedule the two transactions at the same time - `A <= '1', '0' after 5 sec;`. For the two successive signal assignment statements the default delay model is **inertial** which means the *old* transaction (from the first assignment) is removed from the *projected output waveform* (a queue, signal updates do not occur in the same part of a simulation cycle that process statements execute in). IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5 Signal assignment statement, 14.7 Execution of a model.

Comment: Note that the delay is ignored in synthesis.

Answer (score 1):

No. It does this:

i) Schedule the setting of `A` to `'1'` *on the next simulation (or delta) cycle*.

ii) No. On second thoughts, don't do that. *Instead*, schedule the setting of `A` to `'0'` in 5 seconds time.

When a *signal assignment operator* is executed in VHDL, it *does not* drive the signal immediately. Instead it schedules a change on the signal (called an *event*) to be actioned some time in the future. If you do not specify a delay, then the event will be actioned on the next *simulation (or delta) cycle*. If VHDL encounters another signal assigment to the same signal, before it has actioned any previous ones, the corresponding events (usually) get deleted and replaced with the new one.

That might sound daft, but it is for good reasons. Replace your code with:

```
A <= '1';
wait for 5 sec;
A <= '0';
```

Comment: This piece of code works on a simple process. But if I want to implement it in a process with a sensitivity list then "wait for" is not available. And if I change it into a process with "wait until", the compiler tells me "wait for" needs an until statement. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You cannot combine a sensitivity list with any kind of wait statement in VHDL. However, you can replace your sensitivity list with `wait on SIGNAL1, SIGNAL2, ... ;` Because all processes execute at time 0, you ought to put that last in your process if you want it to behave _exactly_ the same as it did with the sensitivity list.